# GitLab Grouping Issue

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created a gitlab project with group,subgroup and projects as described below.
The concern over here, is when partnerA user logs in, is able to see the project data under 'subgrp-Spain-partnerA' and 'subgrp-Greece-partnerA' but when spain OpCo user logs in is not able to see project files under subgroup 'subgrp-Spain-partnerA' and 'subgrp-Spain-partnerB' although these subgroups are invited under 'subgrp-spain'.

Ideally as per my knowledge when I invite a group/subgroup the content under it has to be accessible.

I've created users and created subgroups and access to them with highest access permission.

Could you please have a look and let me know what is the gap over here?

[image]

Comment: can you include what roles people have? That's a large part of troubleshooting any permission issue

Comment: Thank you for replying @Arty-chan - for testing purpose I've assigned them Owner role

Comment: Everywhere or only in one of the subgroups?

Comment: everywhere..for users and all subgroups just to leverage and ensure it is working

Answer (score 1):

Reading over your description, I think you might have it backwards.

It looks like your goal is for users in `subgrp-spain` to have access to `subgrp-Spain-partnerA` and `subgrp-Spain-partnerB`.

As explained in the [share group with group documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/manage.html#share-a-group-with-another-group), you need to "invite" another group to have access to it.

So in your case, you want to invite the group to each one.

1. In `subgrp-Spain-partnerA`, invite `subgrp-spain`.
2. In `subgrp-Spain-partnerB`, invite `subgrp-spain`.

Comment: Hi @Arty-chan, Yes, when I had invited the group other way around then it started working absolutely as expected. 
From subgrp-Spain-partnerA I had made an invite of subgrp-spain - likewise for subgrp-Spain-partnerA

Thank you very much Arty-chan

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer fixed your issue, please consider making the accepted answer =)